# Logrotate - compressing, moving, and deleting

Tags: unix, logging, delete-file, logrotate

I'm working with a bunch of logs generated from a script that outputs one logfile per instance of what the script is running over.  Once logfiles are generated, they are not modified or appended.

I can't find any way to simply compress and *move* the logfiles to the archive directory without keeping the original files around at 0 bytes.

The following config does exactly what I want, but doesn't remove the original (now 0 byte) files.

```
/home/queue_data/*.debug {
    size 1k
    rotate 36500
    olddir log_archive/
}
```

Changing rotate to 0 seems like it might do what I want, but it just deleted the contents of the logfiles and didn't compress/move it into the log_archive folder.

I understand this is a different use-case than logrotate is normally used for, but it would be nice to have a centralized system for archiving logfiles without relying on additional cleanup scripts.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `nocreate` option is for:

> `nocreate`
>   New  log  files  are  not  created  (this  overrides  the `create` option).

See also: [the `logrotate(8)` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/logrotate.8.html)

Comment: I guess I was looking for different verbiage.  This works perfectly, thanks for the information.